# How to enqueue JavaScripts in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script

I am struggling a lot this time working on including a JavaScript files in plugin folder.

I am trying to create a plugin by transferring widget files from themes directory.
I copied the widget file, but that widget file was depending on a JavaScript file so I created a /js/ folder in plugin directory. where this files is hosted "jquery.repeatable.js"

I used this code, but it doesn't seems to include the js file -

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script()
{   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.repeatable.js' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

I searched this on forum-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489615/call-a-js-file-from-a-plugin-directory

But still this was not helpful.

I am re-summarizing my question.
In my plugin directory there is a js file under this folder - /js/

I wish to include it what is the correct process, do I need to register something also?

Is there something wrong with this portion - `'admin_enqueue_scripts'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This doesnt work for Plugin get\_template\_directory\_uri()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216837/this-doesnt-work-for-plugin-get-template-directory-uri)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but it will load the script only in admin area beacuse you are enqueuing the script in [`admin_enqueue_scripts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

To load the script in frontend, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` action (which is not the same that [`wp_enqueue_script()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)):

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.repeatable.js' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

Also, that script seems to depends on jQuery, so you should declare that dependencie or the script can be loaded before jQuery and it won't work. Also, I strongly recommend to declare the version of the scripot. This way, if you update the script to a new version, the browser will donwload it again and discard the copy it may have on cache.

For example, if the version of the script is 1.0:

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.repeatable.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

If you want to load it in admin area:

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.repeatable.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

Answer (score 4):

I normally use [plugins_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) method to achieve enqueue.

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script()
{   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('js/jquery.repeatable.js', __FILE__ ), '1.0.0', false );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

Comment: This is better answer than accepted one, since plugin_dir_url() uses plugins_url(); it is unnecessary overhead of one more function call

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

Use this code instead

```
function Zumper_widget_enqueue_script()
{   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/jquery.repeatable.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Zumper_widget_enqueue_script');
```

3rd parameter is to declare dependency and 4th one is to define version.

Set 5rd parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()` to `true`. That's meaning, this file will be loaded in footer.

Comment: Third parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()` is to declare the script dependencies. The fifth paramater is the one to choose if you want to load the script in the footer or in the header. Anyway, I don't think th place to loaded makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks. I read somewhere in some other plugin that some one is doing like this - 

wp_enqueue_script('zumper',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.zumper.min.js',array('jquery'),false,true);

You said setting 3rd to true means it will loaded in footer, then what does this false,true combination means?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does it work?