# How to implement color picker from wordpress in my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, color-picker

I'm having difficulty implementing the color picker exactly the same as WordPress in my plugin.

Is there any official wordpress documentation on how to use this feature?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/

### 1. You should enqueue scripts and styles...

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'mw_enqueue_color_picker' );
function mw_enqueue_color_picker( $hook_suffix ) {
    // first check that $hook_suffix is appropriate for your admin page
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-handle', plugins_url('my-script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
}
```

### 2. ... add an input...

```
<input type="text" value="#bada55" class="my-color-field" data-default-color="#effeff" />
```

### 3. ... and call wpColorPicker function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.my-color-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Comment: You enqueue scripts and styles incorrectly, so they're not loading at all. Why? Because you provide incorrect url to these files. As a path you use `plugins_url( 'personalize-wp-login/js/bootstrap.min.js' )` and it doubles `personalize-wp-login` part. Take a look at this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216881/34172

Comment: Perfect solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

We need to wp_enqueue_script the script and wp_enqueue_style the style with add_action to the functions.php file. Just include a jQuery file and stylesheet file by this script.

```
// Register Scripts &amp; Styles in Admin panel
function custom_color_picker_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'iris', admin_url( 'js/iris.min.js' ), array( 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-touch-punch' ), false, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script( 'cp-active', plugins_url('/js/cp-active.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', custom_color_picker_scripts);
```

Now create a new javascript file as like cp-active.js and keep it avobe defined “/js/cp-active.js” file path using bellows code.

```
jQuery('.color-picker').iris({
// or in the data-default-color attribute on the input
defaultColor: true,
// a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
change: function(event, ui){},
// a callback to fire when the input is emptied or an invalid color
clear: function() {},
// hide the color picker controls on load
hide: true,
// show a group of common colors beneath the square
palettes: true
});
```

Add a textbox to your settings page with a CSS class for the color picker, where you want to dispaly the input text. I have use “color_code” for input $variable.

```
<input id="color_code" class="color-picker" name="color_code" type="text" value="" />
```

Please see more details on [Add jQuery Color Picker WordPress Theme or Plugin](https://www.e2softsolution.com/jquery-color-picker-wordpress/)