# How to implement color picker from WordPress in my boilerplate plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, color-picker

I have seen this reply before:
[How to implement color picker from wordpress in my plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304285/how-to-implement-color-picker-from-wordpress-in-my-plugin)

But I personally still don't quite understand how I can add it in my plugin that follows the boilerplate structure.

Can someone explain it to me better? And where do I get the files for the color picker from? Thanks!

Comment: What is this boilerplate structure you're using? Which part of the answer in the other question are having difficulties with? WP ships with the color picker script file so you don't need get it yourself from anywhere. Just enqueue it as described in the answer and the script will be available for you to use in your own scripts.

Comment: I used this site to generate the boilerplate: https://wppb.me/

Comment: I've already tried following that documentation, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: could you edit your question and include the relevant parts of your code to show how you tried to implement the code example from the other question's answer, please?